# Make a containerView's viewController bigger than the containerView size. Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

Can I make a containerView's viewController bigger than the containerView size? I was looking to increase the size of the containerView programatically when a button is clicked so that it shows the rest of its viewController's content. I tried doing that but the containerView seems to spill (everything that is out of its frame size) on the parent view.

Comment: Try to use scroll view, you can set it size and content size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can certainly do this. But you may find autolayout wants to fight with you on it. When you say that content 'spills' I think you mean that your child view controller's view is drawing outside of its container. Make sure you set the 'clipsToBounds' property on your container view to YES (or true in swift)
Best.

Comment: Awesome! ticked the "Clip Subviews" checkbox of the containerView through the attributes inspector and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I am having a hard time accomplishing this. Does this work for an embed segue as well, because the 'clipsToBounds' property on my container view is set to YES, but that doesn't seem to help.